# If $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-6}{x-1} = 10$, then what is $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$?

Tags: limits

I was given this question:

> If 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-6}{x-1} = 10$$
>   then what is 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$$

I am assuming that I will need to use limit laws in reverse, but this doesn't seem to work as the limit of $x-1$ as $x$ approaches $1$ is $0$, which gives an undefined answer.

Comment: Hint: do you see why it's impossible for $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)=123$? Can you generalize that observation to rule out other possible values for $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Assume that $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)=123$, and then evaluate $\lim_{x\to1} (f(x)-6)/(x-1)$ directly.

Comment: (123-6)/(1-1)=117/0. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Exactly. 117/0 makes no sense, but something else over zero makes *slightly* more sense

Comment: Is the heuristic answer $117/0$ compatible with the information given that the answer should be $10$?

Comment: But 0/0 is still undefined. I put in 6 because lim f(x)-6=0 so limf(x) = 6, but how can it be correct to leave it over 0?

Comment: @Nate.Olson Suppose $f(x) = 10x - 4$. Then $\frac{f(x) - 6}{x -1} = \frac{10x - 10}{x-1}$. Then for $x \neq 1$, you get $\frac{f(x) - 6}{x -1} = 10$, so $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x) - 6}{x -1} = 10$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 6$. Of course, $f(x)$ can be another function with similar type behavior (i.e., goes to $6$ as $x \to 1$ but the ratio with $x - 1$ goes to $10$), but here's one example where $0$ over $0$ at the limiting value becomes $10$ instead.

Comment: @Nate.Olson I just noticed my example function was given earlier in an answer by Vizag below.

Answer (score 10):

Let $\alpha: \Bbb{R} \setminus\{1\} \to \Bbb{R}$ be the function defined by 
\begin{align}
\alpha(x) = \dfrac{f(x)-6}{x-1}
\end{align}
Then, by assumption, $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\alpha(x) = 10$. Also, it's easy to see that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1}(x-1) = 0$. Hence, by the rules for products of limits, we know that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \big(\alpha(x) \cdot (x-1) \big)$ exists and:
\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \bigg(\alpha(x) \cdot (x-1) \bigg) &= \bigg(\lim_{x \to 1} \alpha(x) \bigg) \cdot \bigg( \lim_{x \to 1}(x-1)\bigg) \\
&= (10) \cdot 0 \\
&= 0 \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

But, now, let's examine the LHS more carefully. If $x \neq 1$, what is $\alpha(x) \cdot (x-1)$? Well, let's go back to the definition of $\alpha$. It should be clear that if $x \neq 1$, then $\alpha(x) \cdot(x-1) = f(x)-6$. Hence, what $(*)$ shows is that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1} \bigg( f(x) - 6 \bigg) = 0
\end{align}
or equivalently,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 6
\end{align}

---

The thought process I had when approaching this question is that we are interested in the limit of $f(x)$, and $f(x)$ appears in the numerator. Typically, I would use the rule
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\dfrac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} \bigg) = \dfrac{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \phi(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \psi(x)}
\end{align}
but in this case, we cannot directly apply this rule, because this rule is only valid when $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \psi(x) \neq 0$ (division by zero is your worst enemy in math!). In this case, the denominator $x-1$ clearly has a limit of $0$ as $x \to 1$.

Therefore, to get around this obstacle, the most natural thing to do is simply "get rid of" the denominator by multiplying the denominator throughout, and as you can see, this was pretty much the idea behind my proof above.

Hopefully this helps you with not only the proof, but more importantly how to think about approaching such problems.

Answer (score 3):

Since the limit as $x\to 1$ of the denominator is 0, the entire expression must explode to $\pm \infty$ if the limit of the numerator is nonzero. Therefore, since the limit exists, it must hold that $\lim_{x\to 1} (f(x) - 6)=0$. Thus $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=6$.

Comment: You did not prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}(f(x)-6)$ exists. If you'll see down-voting it's not mine.

Comment: Yes, I know. I felt it was not extremely important given how the question was asked. But you're right that it's very important to show that. Peek-a-boo has given a more detailed answer which exhausts this

Comment: See also my answer.

Comment: Noted, yours does give a quick way to see existence! It also calculates the value cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

The limit will exist if $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 6$. For example take $f(x) = 10x -4$ in which case, the given condition holds and the limit of the ratio is indeed $10$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-6}{x-1}}^{10}\overbrace{\vphantom{\frac61}\lim_{x\to1}(x-1)}^0
&=\overbrace{\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-6}{x-1}(x-1)}^{10\,\cdot\,0}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}(f(x)-6)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon>0$, by definition, we can find $\delta_1>0$ such that 
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-6}{x-1}-10\right|<\epsilon \ \text{for all } 0<|x-1|<\delta_1,$$
So 
$$|(f(x)-6)-10(x-1)|<\epsilon|x-1| \ \text{for all } 0<|x-1|<\delta_1.$$
Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\frac12,\frac{\epsilon}{20}\},$ then for all $0<|x-1|<\delta$, we have
$$|f(x)-6|\leq |(f(x)-6)-10(x-1)|+10|x-1|<\epsilon\delta+10\delta\leq \frac12\epsilon+\frac12\epsilon=\epsilon.$$
By definition, we have $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=6$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just another way.*

Making the problem more general and admiting that the function is well-conditioned, using Taylor series around $x=a$
$$f(x)=f(a)+ f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}  f''(a)(x-a)^2+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$

$$\frac{f(x)-b}{x-a}=\frac{f(a)-b}{x-a}+f'(a)+\frac{1}{2}  f''(a)(x-a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ So, to have 
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-b}{x-a} = c$$ you need $f(a)=b$ and $f'(a)=c$.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(f(x)-6)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

A full solution:

We have:
 $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)=6+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}(f(x)-6)=6+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{f(x)-6}{x-1}\cdot(x-1)\right)=$$
$$=6+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{f(x)-6}{x-1}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}(x-1)=6+10\cdot0=6.$$

Comment: Why would that make the problem possible?

Comment: Because it gives you 0/0 for your expression at x=1.

Comment: @Nate.Olson I added something. See now.

Comment: @Michael Rosenberg this does sufficiently prove the existence of the limit!